# jQuery: changing element value after serialized

Tags: jquery, serialization

If i have my form elements with values in variable `data` (contains: `var data = $(this).serializeArray();`)

How can i do change the value of an form element (called recipient), when it's inside data?

So my element with `name=recipient` have value "mama", how can I change it to "papa" on ajax success

Comment: your question, is little fuzzy, you may want change form field with new one that come from an ajax request; in which format!? json, xml or html!?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can iterate through your objects in the array, change the object's value:

```
for (var item in data)
{
  if (data[item].name == 'recipient') {
    data[item].value = 'papa';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$.each(data, function(key, data)
{
    if (this.name == "recipient") 
        this.value="papa";
});
```